# Is there a way to make a body field automatically become the first comment on a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, comments

Im on d7, I want my body field (or any textfield attached to a content  type really) to automatically become the first comment on its node. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what your use case is for this, just curious.

Comment: Basically I want to encourage users to comment on content. People are more inclined to do so when there are comments present, making the content "talked about".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without coding, I'd go for the module [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) :
You can create action that are triggered after certain events, under certain conditions.
In your case you can try to create a rule like this one :

- Event : When a Node is Created
- Conditions : You probably want to filter the node type maybe ?
- Action : Create an entity

  - Select Comment as your entity type
  - Node referencing the comment : Use the available token "node" (the newly created node that triggered your rule)
  - Comment body : Use the available token node:body

And you're done .. 0 code, 1 module, 2 mins to setup your rule :-)